# Call automatically JS function with parameters inside <div> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I've tried to find answers on internet to this.. but I didn't find :(
I'm trying to call automatically a javascript function passing parameters inside a < div > element when the page is loaded.
I know that "onload" doesn't work on < div > elements. I don't have idea how to do that.

Note..: My parameters are dynamics because it's inside a foreach loop. Each loop I have 2 different parameters to send to the function.

```
@foreach(var i in Something)  
{  
  <div onload="myFunction(i.param1, i.param2);">  
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Add your Javascript function also

Comment: why don't you use `<body onload="">`?

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to do this? Specifying that will probably get you an answer explaining how to achieve this in a different and better way.

Comment: Ok. take a look now. Is it better? hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a script block at the end of your `<div>`:

```
<div>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        myFunction(dynam_param1, dynam_param2);
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it worked good. I created a new <script> tag on the top of the page to make my function be global, so i can call it like you said. I dont know if its a great code.. but worked good.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. There are better ways using handlers for AJAX events, but this is way easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the function when the page is loaded then you can put the `onload` in the `<body>` tag

```
<body onload="myFunction(dynam_param1, dynam_param2);">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: I have updated my jsFiddle to show how to do using single script tag.

Assume below code is generated thru for loop.

```
<div class="dynamic-div" data-dynamic1='1' data-dynamic2='a'> 
    1
</div>
<div class="dynamic-div" data-dynamic1='2' data-dynamic2='b'> 
    2
</div>
```

So in your ready method you can get all the divs with class dyanmic-div and then do your process

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){
    $(".dynamic-div").each(function(index, element){
          var $this = $(element);
          myFunction($this.attr("data-dynamic1") , $this.attr("data-dynamic2"));            
    });
});

function myFunction(arg1, arg2){
    alert(arg1 + " - " +  arg2);            
}
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/q8qzfavv](http://jsfiddle.net/q8qzfavv/2)

Here you can replace alert with your function call or any other operation that you plan to perform.